# Nservice bus queue not found exception

Tags: nservicebus

I have a connector( which receives messages from different connectors. While receiving the message my connector gives the following message:

> [Worker.11] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transact
>   ional.TransactionalTransport [(null)] <(null)> - Failed raising 'transport messa
>   ge received' event for message with ID=fd970068-55ad-49c0-8abc-4133b7f7fe12\2138
>   47
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException ---> System.Messaging.Message
>   QueueException: Cannot enlist the transaction.
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransac
>   tion internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.NServiceBus.Unicast.Que
>   uing.ISendMessages.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilde
>   r, TransportMessage msg)
>      at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, Tra
>   nsportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
>      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
>      at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTrans
>   portMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)

The weird thing is when i was doing the internal testing it was working all fine as soon as this has been now hosted on to amazon server it has started blowing up.

The following is how i have configured my nservice bus with

```
NServiceBus.Configure.With(
            AllAssemblies.Except("libBL.dll").And("libCommon.dll").And("libExtra.dll")).StructureMapBuilder()
            .JsonSerializer()
            .UnicastBus()
            .DoNotAutoSubscribe()
            .TransactionTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If any more information is needed please let me know

Thanks

Comment: The local queue will be created automatically. Perhaps you have another queue mapped to by this endpoint which has yet to be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On searching through the code found out that if a message coming in was failing then i was  not rolling back the transaction in which the whole operation began and hence the nservicebus was not able to query the database as it was locked. After putting in the logic for transaction roll back got my connector to work.